# php code for each wordpress widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, customization, themes

I'm currently changing my theme and I need each individual code of each widget.

For example I need the rss widget, or categories widget or comment widget, etc.

I want those widget integrated in my footer.

Where can I see the code? I have no idea where to begin look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend creating [multiple sidebar regions](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2007/11/how-to-create-multiple-dynamic-sidebars-for-wordpress-widgets/) in your footer. You can make as many as you like, so just make one for each widget you'd like to have in the footer.

This way, you benefit from updates to the core widgets when WordPress tweaks them.